# What should i put in the method startactivity?

Tags: android

I'm creating an app with a listview. I would like to go from an item in the listview to an other activity. I have the following code:

```
    package be.intec.brussel;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Topstores<TextView> extends Activity{




    String[] items = {"C&A", "H&M","Esprit", "Tommy Hilfinger", "Shoe Discount", "Brantano", "Bell&Bo", "Scapino", "Zara", "Kruidvat"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.topstores);
        ListView ShopView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ShopView);





        ShopView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.test_list_item, items));

    }


    protected void onListItemClick(ListView ShopView, View v, int position, long id) {
        if("C&A".equals(items[position])){
            startActivity(Rating.class);
        }

    }


    private void startActivity(Class<Rating> class1) {


    }
}
```

My question is: What should i put after the startactivity method?

And i also want to know how you can set the name (title) of the item in an textview on the other activity?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think no need to create method like `startActivity`  because already we have...

```
ListView ShopView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ShopView);
ShopView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.test_list_item, items));
ShopView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                        long arg3) {

               if("C&A".equals(items[position])){
                       Intent intent = new Intent(Topstores.this,Rating.class);
                       intent.putExtra("itemname",items[position]); 
                       startActivity(intent);
                }
          }});
```

**Now in Rating Activity...**

```
class Rating extends Activity{

    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ratingxml);

   Bundle b =getIntent().getExtras();
   String itemname = b.getString("itemname");//here you get name 
   System.out.println(itemname);

   textview.setText(itemname);//here set item in textview

    }
}
```

Comment: are you declare activity in manifest file?`and does not go to rating means ?` any error ?

Comment: Yes, i declared the activity in the manifest file. If i click on "C&A" it does not open the rating activity.

Comment: hmmm...ShopView.setonItemClickListener(this)

Comment: Now he asks to put something in the onClick method. Should i put the code in it from the onListItemClick?

Comment: I'm reading it carefully but in youre code there isn't an onClick method. Sorry for all the questions but i am just starting with android.

Comment: see my upadate answer and use `onItemClick` instead of `onClick`

Answer (score 0):

```
private void startActivity(Class<Rating> clazz) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Topstores.this, clazz);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The code creates an explicit intent to the Rating class and starts the Rating activity.